# Providing Generic Exception handler in spring boot convetring all exception into HTTP 500

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

In my application I have provided handlers to specific and Generic Exception (`Exception.class`) both. Problem is whenever wrong input is provided to API it's expected to throw `BAD REQUEST`(HTTP-400). However, it's returning HTTP-500 in case of BAD requests. Validations spring boot automatically trigger itself however that is being caught by handleApplicationException.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> handleApplicationException(final Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("Unhandled Exception occurred ", ex);

    ErrorResponseDTO errorResponseDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO();
    errorResponseDTO.setMessage("Internal Server Error");
    errorResponseDTO.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(errorResponseDTO);
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> handleResourceNotFoundException(final ResourceNotFoundException
    notFoundException) {

    LOGGER.error("Handling resource not found exception", notFoundException);
    ErrorResponseDTO errorResponseDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO();
    errorResponseDTO.setMessage(notFoundException.getMessage());
    errorResponseDTO.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errorResponseDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see providing an exception handler for `Exception` class as a bad practice. Most of the **exceptions** usually inherit from the `Exception` class and in turn, are caught by your `handleApplicationException` handler.

> Focus on handling specific exceptions.

For example, if the client sends a bad formatted JSON an `HttpMessageNotReadableException` is thrown, you can catch that in your **Exception Handler** and do what you want with it, or by simply removing your **Exception Handler** for the `Exception.class` Spring will return a `400 - BAD REQUEST` response.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I was thinking to not to have Exception.class handler. But In this case some unknown exception was thrown away to UI. I was looking for some way not catch spring related exception and still get advantage of automatic Bad request conversion. I could provide handler for "HttpMessageNotReadableException " but in this case if This exception changes in future then again I have to search for with what it has been replace.

Comment: Usually, exceptions do not change over time. Just focus on your specific Exceptions, there are not that many to be handled. Also, I do not fully understand what you mean by "some way not catch spring related exception and still get advantage of automatic Bad request conversion".

Comment: If we do not register 'HttpMessageNotReadableException ' handler Spring still automatically can detect and convert this into HTTP-400. I mean is there anyway we can let do this spring while we are registering 'Exception.Class' handler.

Comment: There is no way as the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` inherits from `Exception`. I don't think that there is a case when you need to handle the `Exception.class`.